# Rails ActiveRecord includes all associations after matching query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Doing a query in Rails like this to find Photos with Tags by tag_id preloads Tags on the Photos, but only those Tags that match the tag_ids in the query... This gets exposed when the photos get serialized later..

How do I keep all the associated Tags, and return the Photos that have those specific tags?

Using this query: `Photo.includes(:tags).where("tags.id IN (?)", [2, 5, 10).references(:tags)`

I want all Photos that have tags 2, 5, and 10, but if a Photo has tag 2 and 3, I want it to include tag 3 in its response.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do it, but I think this works.

```
# Build a query for all photo IDs that have the specified tags.
photo_ids_query = Photo.joins(:tags)
                       .where(:tags => { :id => [2, 5, 10] })
                       .select("photos.id")

# Load that list of photo IDs using a subquery.
Photo.includes(:tags)
     .where("photos.id IN (#{photo_ids_query.to_sql})")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with a single join, because you can't simultaneously restrict that joined table to only those records with specific IDs and *not* restrict it.

I think you would be able to do this with Arel, but you would need 2 joins: one to restrict with the `where tags.id in (...)` (you'd give it a table alias) and one to get *all* the `Tag`s joined to each of the `Photo`s that's returned (the default one so that it would be the one used by association methods, like `photo.tags`).

Maybe something like this...

```rb
photos = Photo.arel_table
restricted_tags = Tag.arel_table.alias(:restricted_tags)
Photo.
  includes(:tags).
  joins(
    photos.join(restricted_tags).on(
      tags[:photo_id].eq(photos[:id])  # or whatever your join conditions are in your particular case
    ).join_sources
  ).where(
    restricted_tags.in([2, 5, 10])
  )
```